# Understanding in detail the following proof (an undergraduate trying to understand a graduate proof).

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I've been reading the book "Algebra a graduate course" by Isaacs, but I met something in Galois Theory that I didn't understand  this proof

(18.13) THEOREM. Let $F \subset Ε$ with $[E : F] < \infty$. The following are then
equivalent:

i. $Ε$ is a Galois extension of $F$.

ii. $Ε$ is both separable and normal over $F$.

iii. $Ε$ is a splitting field over $F$ for some separable polynomial over $F$.

To show that (iii) implies (i), assume that $E$ is a splitting field over $F$ for
some polynomial $g \in F[X]$ that is separable over $F$. Let $G = Gal(E/F)$ and
write $К = Fix(G)$. We need to show that $К = F.$

There is nothing to prove if $Ε = F$, and so we can work by induction on
$[E : F]$ and assume that $Ε > F$. Since $Ε$ is generated over $F$ by roots of $g$,there must be some root a of $g$ with $\alpha \in E — F$. Then $[F : F[\alpha]] < [E : F]$ and
$E$ is a splitting field for $g$ over $F[\alpha]$. Also, $g$ is separable over $F[\alpha]$ by Lemma 18.10, and thus the inductive hypothesis guarantees that $Ε$ is Galois over $F[\alpha]$.

Since $Gal(E/F[\alpha]) \subset G$, we have $$F[\alpha] = Fix(Gal(F/F[\alpha])) \supset Fix(G) = K.$$
Let $f = min_F(\alpha)$. Since $g(\alpha) = 0$, we have $f|_g$ and thus $f$ splits over $E$.

Write $Ω$ to denote the set of roots of $f$ in $E$, and note that since $g$ is separable, we know that $f$ has distinct roots and hence $|Ω| = deg(f)$. By Lemma 18.3 we deduce that $G$ acts on $Ω$ and that the whole set $Ω$ is a single orbit.
Now let $h = min_K(\alpha)$· Since $К = Fix(G)$, we see that $G \subset Gal(E/F)$,
and thus by Lemma 18.3(a), $G$ permutes the roots of $h$ in $E$. Since $\alpha$ is one of these roots, so also is each element $σ(α)$ for all $σ \in G$. It follows that every element of $Ω$ is a root of $h$, and we have $$[K[\alpha] : K] = deg(h) > |Ω| = deg(f) = [F[\alpha] : F].$$

Since $F \subset K \subset F[\alpha]$, we see that $K[\alpha] = F[\alpha]$, and our inequality yields
$$[F[\alpha] : K][K : F] = [F[\alpha] : F] < [K[\alpha] : K] = [F[\alpha] : K].$$
We deduce that $[K : F]= 1$ and $ K= F$, as required. ■

The thing is that I don't get why we have that $f|_g$, How can we restrict a polynomial to a polynomial?, and the other thing, is that I think is a little bit involve, so Can someone clarify a little bit this procedure please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it, thanks :)

Comment: I'm looking at my copy of Isaacs. You are misreading: he wrote $f \mid g$ ($f$ divides $g$), not $f|_g$.

Comment: Ok jajajaja :) , and why is it involved , or well , Is there a better way of doing this for a undergraduate? Jajajaja thanks

Comment: I think Isaacs gives enough detail in his proofs that it should be accessible to an undergraduate, but of course that depends on your background. Have you ever studied Galois theory before? You could check an undergraduate book like Fraleigh or Dummit and Foote to see if it is easier to understand.

Comment: Ok, so let me check those, and if I still stuck can I let you know ?

Comment: If you have a specific question about the proof (in Isaacs or elsewhere), you can edit the question above to clarify what part you don't understand.

Comment: Right, just let me check the other references and I let you know right, just give some time right? :)

Comment: In my upbringing, “Galois” *means* normal and separable. So Isaacs must have used a different definition. Could you say what that is?

Comment: Fix(Gal(E/F))=F and [E:F]<oo sorry for the delay